# How to click on Log In button/link data-testid using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am attempting to click on 'Log in' but my Selenium code isn't working. Below is the HTML code.

```
<span class="css-14krylx-text-text-fullPageText-FormFooter">Already have a Times account? 
<span tabindex="0" data-testid="switch-to-login" class="css-dip6gw-link-link-FormFooter">Log in</span></span>
```

What I attempted so far and did not work?

1. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-testid='switch-to-login'")).click();`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-testid='switch-to-login'")).click();`
3. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("/.css-dip6gw-link-link-FormFooter'")).click();`

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span[class$='text-text-fullPageText-FormFooter'] span[class$='link-link-FormFooter'][data-testid='switch-to-login']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'text-text-fullPageText-FormFooter')]//span[contains(@class, 'link-link-FormFooter') and text()='Log in']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hello DebanjanB - the cssSelector approach appears to have worked. Thanks so much. You are awesome.